# Java calculate ISBN using for loop

Tags: java

I am still new to Java, this question like: An ISBN-10 (International Standard Book Number)
consists of 10 digits: d1d2d3d4d5d6d7d8d9d10. The last digit, d10, is a checksum,
which is calculated from the other nine digits using the following formula:
(d1 * 1 + d2 * 2 + d3 * 3 + d4 * 4 + d5 * 5 +
d6 * 6 + d7 * 7 + d8 * 8 + d9 * 9) % 11
If the checksum is 10, the last digit is denoted as X according to the ISBN-10
convention. Write a program that prompts the user to enter the first 9 digits and
displays the 10-digit ISBN (including leading zeros). Your program should read
the input as an integer.

**See my code below:**
It is working but the result is not correct!

```
public static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter first 9 digit numbers: ");
        int[] arr = new int[9];
        int checkSum = 0;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = input.nextInt();
            checkSum = (arr[i] * i) % 11;   
        }
        System.out.print("The ISBN-10 Number is " );
        for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[j]);
        }

        if(checkSum == 10)
        {
            System.out.println("x");
        } 
        else
        {
            System.out.println(checkSum);
        }
```

I just want to use loop, make my method works. , i know how to use method without loop.

Comment: Well, Java uses `0-based` indexing for arrays. So, you if you declare and array as `int[] arr = new int[9];`. You have 9 elements which can be indexed using `0 to 8`. In example B, you are using `1-9`, here `9` means accessing the `10th` element which does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

well. for JAVA
an array index start from 0. and Max index is length － 1.
if the index is not within this range. an arrayoutofbounds exception will be thrown

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that you are doing `int i = 1` instead of `int i = 0`. The problem is that you changed `i < arr.length;` to `i <= arr.length;`. Since `arr.length` is 9, your code is trying to refer to `arr[9]` but `arr` only has elements `arr[0]` through `arr[8]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = new int[9];
```

This means the array has 9 slots. And the numbering of those slots starts from 0. Thus,

- arr[0] is the first slot
- arr[1] is the second slot

The last slot would be arr[8]. But in the following code you are iterating till i is equal to 9 which does not exist.

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= arr.length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = input.nextInt();
        checkSum = (arr[i] * (i+1)) % 11;   
    }
```

This results in the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Change `for (int i = 1 ; i <= arr.length; i++)` to `for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++)`

Comment: I cannot change to i = 0; because  arr[i] * i == 0; it won't be correct for my question.

Comment: Of course you should use ```arr[i] * (i+1) == 0```

Comment: Then it will be arr[0]*1 + arr[1] * 2 + ... it is not correct.

Comment: ```arr[0]``` is d1, ```arr[1]``` is d2. Thus this is correct. As many answers above have pointed out, java uses a 0-based array index.

Answer (score 0):

First, review how we use arrays...

```
int[] I = new int[3];
```

The above creates an array with 3 spots in it. After instantiating the array, each element is based off of a 0-index. You only have I[0], I[1], and I[2] available (note this is three numbers) and trying to access I[3] will throw the error that you encountered in your program above: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

That being said, your loop is trying to access arr[9]. The highest index you have in the array is arr[8], because despite the array having 9 elements in it, it's 0-indexed.

Assuming you MUST have `i` starting from 1 for a homework assignment or something, change your code to:

```
public static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter first 9 digit numbers: ");
        int[] arr = new int[9];
        int checkSum = 0;

        for (int i = 1 ; i <= arr.length; i++)
        {
            arr[i-1] = input.nextInt();
            checkSum = (arr[i-1] * i) % 11;   
        }
        System.out.print("The ISBN-10 Number is " );
        for(int j = 1 ; j <= arr.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[j-1]);
        }

        if(checkSum == 10)
        {
            System.out.println("x");
        } 
        else
        {
            System.out.println(checkSum);
        }
```

Comment: It is not correct, sir. because it has to be a[i]*i, like a[2]*2. Can't be a[1] * 2;